# ng-include [parse:syntax] error when adding moment-picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, momentjs, datetimepicker

I have a problem implementing [angular-moment-picker](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker) lib for datetimes

Original working template "step1.html":

```
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" ng-model="theDate" name="theDate" view="date" auto-close="true" min-view="date" format="{{$root.getLocalDateFormat()}}" ng-disabled="editPage" required >
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
```

Not working anymore when adding moment-picker:

```
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" moment-picker="jobRecurrence.startDate" ng-model="theDate" name="theDate" view="date" auto-close="true" min-view="date" format="{{$root.getLocalDateFormat()}}" ng-disabled="editPage" required >
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
```

I get the chrome's console error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=…s%20%3D%3D%3D%20'endDate'%20%3F%20jobRecurrence.endDate%20%3A%20null%7D%7D
    at http://localhost:8089/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at s.throwError (http://localhost:8089/lib/angular/angular.min.js:210:32)
    at s.object (http://localhost:8089/lib/angular/angular.min.js:209:327)
    at s.primary (http://localhost:8089/lib/angular/angular.min.js:206:335)
    at s.unary (http://localhost:8089/lib/angular/angular.min.js:206:174)
    at s.multiplicative (http://localhost:8089/lib/angular/angular.min.js:205:434)
    at s.additive (http://localhost:8089/lib/angular/angular.min.js:205:261)
    at s.relational (http://localhost:8089/lib/angular/angular.min.js:205:96)
    at s.equality (http://localhost:8089/lib/angular/angular.min.js:204:425)
    at s.logicalAND (http://localhost:8089/lib/angular/angular.min.js:204:278) <div ng-include="'html/jobRecurrence/wizard/step1.html'" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:107
```

Moment-picker works everywhere else on the app. Only this template creates problems.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue, maybe the problem is the value of `jobRecurrence.startDate`. Can you provide a snippet/fiddle (or something similar) showing the issue?

Comment: Fixed, it was not related to the lib, just an error with a {{}} parameter in a html tag. Thank you for trying to help me though. will delete this post soon.